# Node JS - Convert VARBINARY to .wav file

Tags: node.js, buffer, blob, wav, varbinary

I have an issue in converting a VARBINARY data to wav file in Node.JS

A wav audio is stored as VARBINARY in an MSSQL table. In the following code, "wavImage" is the variable where I have the wav content retrieved  from SQL.

When I print "wavImage", it prints like this:

*< Buffer 52 49 46 46 20 22 05 00 57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20 14 00 00 00 31 00 01 00 40 1f 00 00 59 06 00 00 41 00 00 00 02 00 40 01 64 61 74 61 f7 21 05 00 6a 79 ... >*

I want to save the data as a valid ".wav" file, but none of the attempts tried below seems to work. I tried all kinds of conversion of buffer blindly but no luck.

Could someone please help me out and tell me how to save the VARBINARY to a .wav file.

Many thanks. Here is the sample of the code.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var wav_1 = wavImage;//Retrieved from MSSQL (VARBINARY columNn)
var wav_2 = Buffer.from(wavImage);
var wav_3 = Uint16Array.from(wavImage).buffer;
var wav_4 = Buffer(new Uint8Array(wavImage));
var wav_5 = Buffer.from(new Uint8Array(wavImage));

fs.writeFileSync('wav_1.wav', wav_1);//Did not get a valid .wav file
fs.writeFileSync('wav_2.wav', wav_2);//Did not get a valid .wav file
fs.writeFileSync('wav_3.wav', wav_3);//Did not get a valid .wav file
fs.writeFileSync('wav_4.wav', wav_4);//Did not get a valid .wav file
fs.writeFileSync('wav_5.wav', wav_5);//Did not get a valid .wav file
```

Comment: Could this be an issue with the encoding format for the newly created file? Without an option parameter passed to `writeFileSync()` it accepts a default encoding of `utf-8`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you were right. "utf-8" as the default encoding was the issue. Setting the encoding option to null fixed the issue. Thanks again.